# Apache: mapping multiple directories to the same location

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, static-files

I would like to map multiple directories to the same location with Apache, expecting a behaviour similar to this: suppose that the `/static` location is to be backed by directories `/srv/static1` and `/srv/static2`. Then if `/static/image.png` is requested, I would like Apache to check for files `/srv/static1/image.png` and `/srv/static2/image.png`, in that order. First file found is returned; if neither is found, classical error 404 is sent back.

Of course a solution is to use a script to make a directory of symlinks that point to the right location and use that one, for example in an `Alias` directive. I wonder if there is a more direct way that doesn't require me to deploy additional machinery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily done using mod_rewrite. You can set it up to have a condition that if the file doesn't exist in the first directory, it should look in the second one instead, and so on.

Here's a short sample configuration; for further information please see [the canonical mod_rewrite question](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask) and [apache's mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html).

```
RewriteEngine on

# first try to find it in dir1/...
# ...and if found stop and be happy:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir1/$1 [L]

# second try to find it in dir2/...
# ...and if found stop and be happy:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir2/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir2/$1 [L]

# else go on for other Alias or ScriptAlias directives,
# etc.
RewriteRule ^ - [PT]
```